# How to read XML values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, sqlxml

I have a list of strings as:

```
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("912-123898493");
    list.Add("021-36574864");
    list.Add("021-36513264");
```

I want to convert it in XML and then send it as a parameter to Stored procedure, so that this could be read.

How to read this XML in sql server so that each and every string can be placed in different cell? Please help!!

Comment: You changed your question from "convert it to XML" to "convert it in XML". What do you mean by "covert in XML"?

Answer (score 5):

It depends of what structure your xml will have.
Here's example of how you can read elements xml:

```
declare @Data xml

select @Data = '
<root>
    <value>912-123898493</value>
    <value>021-36574864</value>
    <value>021-36513264</value>
</root>'

select T.C.value('data(.)', 'nvarchar(128)') as [Data]
from @Data.nodes('/root/value') as T(C)
```